# How do derive this result in stat-mech style

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I'm going through (well, at least I'm planning to) Rief's book about statistical mechanic (I want to improve my knowledge). I want to be serious about this so I'm trying to solve as much problem as I can (and understand them). I came upon this one (1.5):

> In a game of a Russian roulette (*not* recommended by the author), one
>   inserts a single cartridge into the drum and of a revolver, leaving
>   the other five chambers of the drum empty. One then spins the drum,
>   aims at one's head, and pulls the trigger.
>   (a) What it the probability
>   of being still alive after playing the game $N$ times?
>   (b) What it the
>   probability of surviving ($N-1$) turns in this game and then being
>   shot the $N$th time one pulls the trigger?
>   (c) What is the mean number
>   of times a player gets the opportunity of pulling the trigger in this
>   macabre game?

I believe that the starting point for (c) is:

$\left \langle n\right \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{(n-1)} \frac{1}{6}$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28n/6%29%2a%285/6%29%5E%28n-1%29&t=crmtb01) tells me this is an exact sum which equals to 6 (logical). I want however, to try and imply the standard derivative trick (and this is why I'm asking this here and not in the math thread):

$\left \langle n\right \rangle = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n} = \frac{1}{6} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}$

But this is an exact sum (that equals to 1) and I can't take it's derivative. I know I could use some table to solve this, the question is if there some way to solve this in a way that a student can do this in the exam?

I hope any of what I wrote is clear and approved by the site policy.

Comment: you can't take the derivative outside the summation symbol -- that is, the two operations don't commute. (When you use the derivative trick in an integral, you take some derivative with respect to some parameter; not the integration variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick works, you just need to apply it differently. The problem is that you are differentiating with respect to $n$, which won't work because you are summing over $n$.

Instead, the sum you wish to evaluate is,

$$\langle n \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}(1-x) = (1-x) \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$
with $x=5/6$. Now this can be written as,

$$\langle n \rangle = (1-x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}  = (1-x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x} -1\right) = 1/(1-x)$$

which gives 6 for x = 5/6.

Comment: Thanks. Reading your answer I realized that I took the wrong derivative. It is bound to happen if you try and solve stuff when you are tired.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left \langle n\right \rangle ~=~ \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}~=~ \left.\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} \right|_{x=\frac{5}{6}}
~=~ \left.\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^n \right|_{x=\frac{5}{6}} $$
$$~=~ \left.\frac{1}{6}\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty  x^n \right|_{x=\frac{5}{6}}
~=~ \left.\frac{1}{6}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x} \right|_{x=\frac{5}{6}}~=~ \left.\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \right|_{x=\frac{5}{6}}~=~6.$$